# About Angier's clone not knowing whether he will be the Prestige or the one in the box

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-prestige

I have read other answers about this but there're still one thing on my mind that was not satisfied.

Assuming Angier had achieved perfect cloning, the one created would be exactly the same to the one who stepped in the machine, holding all of his memory assuming to the point the trap door opens.

It is true that the next clone wouldn't know the feeling of death the previous one experienced but he must certainly know that the one who walks into the machine will be the one who dies. Yet the dialogues in the scene where he's shot revealed that he did not.

I came to this conclusion by this train of thought:

Let's call the original Angier A, any clone that follows will be numbered chronographically. A(1) is a clone of A in a scene where A want to test the machine. Before the test, A puts a pistol aside with the intention of killing himself if the test fails and somehow breaks him or to kill whatever comes out of the other side. The test succeeded. The moment A went for the gun, A(1) immediately understood and tried to tell A that they are the same but was killed. This could have 3 scenarios,

1. The machine does not teleport but makes a clone, meaning the one on the machine will die and the one created will survive if Angier puts a water tank to drown the one who steps in the machine. Then any clone A(i) would hold perfectly clear previous memory and intention of A(i-1) and this pattern goes all the way back to A. Meaning all clone A(i+1) would know of a water tank was set by A(i) under the trap door to kill the A(i) who stepped into the machine while the A(i+1) is created and A(i+1) must do the same to himself when creating A(i+2).
2. The machine teleports A(i), leaving a clone A(i+1) on the spot. This means A was killed by A(1). Later when A(1) performs, A(1) will be on the Prestige and A(2) dies and this patterns goes on by this logic: A(1+i) dies whenever A(1) perform but doesn't change the fact that whoever is left and the scene where he got shot must know precisely who died and who lived.

Yet in the last few lines, A(n) revealed that he and all previous A(i) didn't know whether they would be the Prestige or the one in the box.

3. The machine randomly teleports and makes clones. Sometimes it's A(i) who dies and A(i+1) lives, sometimes otherwise. If so it makes sense that A(n) didn't know but wouldn't this be lazy writing?

Was there something I missed that would explain the scene and dismiss my thoughts or is this a plot hole? And please excuse my English, I'm not very good at it.

Comment: You don’t seem to be actually asking a question here.

Comment: My bad for not explaining my self well enough, maybe it was taken as a rant but I actually want to know if there's any good explaination for this or it's a plot hole
I'll edit my post

Comment: Since the 'clone' has an unbroken experience as Angier back to his childhood - why wouldn't they have a philosophical question about which one dies.  It certainly doesn't seem to be a plot hole.  He has repeated experience as the survivor, but at any moment wonders whether this is his last time.

Comment: This train of thought began from my assumtion that each "clone" must be somewhat slightly different to the previous regarding sentience even with all the memory so A(i) can't be considered as one with A which caused some misunderstanding

Comment: @LongDoan - I think it's more that they are the exact same up until that point -- the point of death of the one, and the creation of another, is where the branch off period would be---so the clone literally picks up where the the previous version/incarnate left off. The only thing that might change this cycle is if somehow a third party intervenes to change either the out come of the casualty loop, which could then allow the new clone to think differently and/or begin to branch off (nurture), should one survive the third party intervention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the idea about not knowing if he would be the one who lives or dies, as well as the way the cloning works.

When one person steps into the machine, and then there are two people after that, neither one of them is the "original" and neither one is the "clone". The one was duplicated into two; for all meaningful purposes, both of them were the original who stepped into the machine. There are 2 people around, one remembers stepping into the machine and then being trapped in the water tank; the other remembers stepping into the machine and then appearing on stage as the prestige.

So what Angier means by not knowing whether he will be the prestige or the one who drowns is more of a philosophical statement; because in reality he will be both. But as the person pre-cloning who is stepping into the machine, he can't tell what the next event he will experience will be; drowning or showing up on stage.

Comment: - I understand this movie approaches this from the standpoint of we are nothing but chemical and neurons firing at each other so if perfect clone is achieved, the "original" and the "created" must be considered as one


- Meanwhile I approached it from the standpoint of we are something beyond that so each clone, even though perfect must have some slight different in consience/ sentience. Maybe that caused misunderstanding


- No judging though, because both standpoints is valid to me since I have no proof to confirm or deny either of them

Comment: @LongDoan: The only difference in the copies (experience, neurons, ...) happens **after** the split, not before. At the exact second the copy is completed, you have two identical copies, who _then_ start experiencing different things. Keep in mind that the Angier who makes the statement is the Angier who in their experience "always was the survivor", but that is simply because **every** Angier remembers to "have always survived" up until the point they effectively die. Every living Angier will always have experienced being the "survivor" up to the point they die.

Answer (score 5):

Tesla's device makes a perfect duplicate of whatever is within the device - one of those duplicates is transported to a predictable location some distance away (the pile of hats) while the other remains within the device.

We do not know which was the original (although, you might assume the original is the one in the device), but it doesn't really matter. Right up until the duplication event, there was one Angiers, and suddenly there are two with the exact same experiences and memories. They may be duplicates, but they are the same person.

Angiers saying he doesn't know which one he'll be is a result that really he ends up as both. The movie sticks with the point-of-view of the transported Angiers, since the drowned Angiers aren't really going to contribute much to the story, but what happens is that every night of the show's run, the Angiers who steps into the device is *both* transported and drowned - but only the transported man survives to continue the show and story.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with both the answers given above, for myself I have always sided with your scenario (1).

Firstly, yes, given two 100% identical beings, both of whom possess the same memories, etc, it is purely philosophical (or even meaningless) to say that one is "the original".  It is also undoubtedly true that when Angier steps into the machine, he knows that his next experience will be either being the Prestige or being drowned.

However, IMHO taking such a hard logical viewpoint would require the mentality of a Spock, and I don't see that in the character.

Notwithstanding the philosophical issues above, I personally cannot see the machine as doing other than "reading" the object inside it and making a perfect copy a predictable distance elsewhere.

As a result, I find a much greater emotional impact than the purely logical view of "OK, I've got a 50-50 chance of my next memory is of being the prestige".

Instead, I view the Angier who steps into the machine KNOWS the he - "the original" - is going to die.  However, he is prepared to pay this ultimate cost for his craft given that the other - "the clone" - will survive and continue.  Using your notation, yes, A(i), and A(i+1), and all the subsequent are each prepared to make this sacrifice, since they are each identical, and so share the same drive to rich this pinnacle of their art (*)

This resolution I find is much more in keeping with the whole theme of the film, fitting Angier in alongside both Borden and the Chinese magician as being so devoted and willing to sacrifice their very selves for the sake of their craft.

(*) and let's not forget, it wasn't only that pinnacle that they wanted, but also the whole show was also a honey-trap to catch Borden - that was the other drive shared by A(i), A(i+1), ... as they were all identical.